# How to use live data to improve a existing model?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, training

I am using logistic regression to train a model to predict 'click/non-click' using ['browser info', 'publisher info', , 'location', 'time', 'day'].

I wanted to know the ways in which I can use the new live data to improve the improve the already trained model.

Does a solution exist which takes into account - change in feature set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a model that has been trained on $N$ data over $E$ epochs. This means that the model has seen each of the $N$ examples, $E$ times.

Now say you got $M$ more training data. Normally you would want to train the new ones for $E$ epochs as well.

However if $N$ and $M$ don't come from the same underlying distribution (or don't represent it adequately), this would result in the model "forgetting" the first $N$ examples and "paying more attention" to the latter $M$ ones.

You could try training your model for $<E$ epochs, so that it learns the latter but doesn't forget the former, but that is purely empirical and very hard to achieve in practice.

You can a few things to avoid this:

1. **Retrain** your whole model using both the $N+M$ examples (which you would shuffle). This would require a new complete training of the model on regular occasions and would be **increasingly** difficult to train (due to the ever increasing size of the training data). This is a **very inefficient** solution and wouldn't work for any on-line training application
2. Make use of a model that supports **on-line training**. Some algorithms support incremental (on-line) training, without you needing to retrain the whole thing. A [scikit-learn comparison](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_comparison.html) is available.
3. Customize an algorithm so that is has the desired effect. For example, you could train a linear SVM incrementally, with a large regularization penalty and an SGD classifier. This is discussed in more detail for scikit-learn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056460/does-the-svm-in-sklearn-support-incremental-online-learning).